# Django admin interface not working in Apache2

Tags: django, django-admin, apache2

I setup Django 1.4 on my testing server and everything works fine, except for the admin interface, which returns either a 404 or 403 error, depending on my configuration.

I also noticed that the "static/admin" directory only contains css, js and img directories.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Here's the relevant part of my apache configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /home/jmetzler/www/public

WSGIDaemonProcess mezgrvm python-path=/home/jmetzler/www/private/py-bin:/home/jmetzler/www/private/py-bin/mezgrman:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=1 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup mezgrvm
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jmetzler/www/private/py-bin/mezgrman/wsgi.py

Alias /admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin

Alias /images /home/jmetzler/www/public/images
Alias /css /home/jmetzler/www/public/css
Alias /error /home/jmetzler/www/public/error

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/jmetzler/www/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 410 /error/410.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you enabled/added admin site in your urls.py?

Comment: Rohan: Yes, I did. I also added an Alias directive in my server configuration, but that doesn't seem to work. The admin interface works when I use the development server that comes with Django.

Comment: If its giving 404 most likely its not configured correctly in urls.py or settings.py, may be you can recheck.

Comment: What else would you expect in static/admin rather than css, js and img?

Comment: I don't know, if that's correct, then fine. It gives an Apache 404, not a Django 404.

Comment: Well you seem to be doing something very odd with your Apache configuration. You should post that.

Comment: OK, I added the relevant part of the configuration.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it would seem your alias to /admin is overriding the url pattern Django expects to find admin on: Alias /admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Alias /admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin` is appropriate in the apache conf.

Your urls.py should be appropriately handling it like
`url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`

If you want to handle static files for admin site, they should reside in your `static` directory, either symlinked or copied.

If you are symlinking admin media, then you should add
`Options +FollowSymLinks` in `Directory` element.
e.g.

```
<Directory "/home/user1/website1/static">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

Comment: Indeed. But now the CSS is missing. I could have sworn that there was a note somewhere that said that one would have to Alias the admin files.

Comment: OK, I fixed my CSS problem now. Can't believe I was SO stupid. Thanks!